# write to plist file

Tags: iphone, plist

I am having head ache for a few hours trying to get to write some info to plist file.
My plist looks like this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>page</key>
    <string>page 1</string>
    <key>description</key>
    <string>description  text 1</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>page</key>
    <string>page 2</string>
    <key>description</key>
    <string>description text 2</string>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I just want to write a new entry to plist like
    
        page
        3
        description
        description text 3

this is the code I use

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bookmark.plist"]; //
NSMutableDictionary *rootArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
[rootArray setObject:@"Jimmy1" forKey:@"page"];
    [rootArray setObject:@"Jimmy2" forKey:@"description"];
    [rootArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

when I run I do not get any error message but just doest write anything to bookmark.plist, could you give me an idea on how to solve this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is you have an array of dicts not a root dictionary. So when you init your `NSMutableDictionary` you're actually getting an array.

I think you need to init an `NSMutableArray`, add a new dictionary as the object that has the objects you want. then write your array to file.

```
NSMutableArray *rootArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSDictionary *newPage = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Page 3", @"page", @"Description text 3", @"description"];

[rootArray addObject:newPage];

[rootArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Haven't checked this in Xcode but I think this is the root of your problem.

**Update**

Definitely check out **Rahul**'s answer. He remembered to wrap the write method in an if statement. This is definitely best practice for error handling.

Comment: cross posted... deleted my now redundant answer!

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'addobject:'

Comment: getting this error message No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'addobject:'

Comment: Sorry @jrturton haha. Glad you're up and running Riccardo, Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is

```
NSMutableDictionary *rootArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];` //it will return you array of dict not dictionary
```

Try this

```
 // get your plist file path    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bookmark.plist"];

// get content of your plist file     
NSMutableArray *rootArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

// create new dictionary with new content
NSDictionary *newPage = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Page 3", @"page", @"Description text 3", @"description"];

// add new dictionnay to your rootArray
[rootArray addObject:newPage];

if([rootArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES]) // it will return bool value
{
   NSLog(@"Successfully finished writing to file");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"failed to write");
}
```

Comment: +1 for wrapping the write in an if statement. Didn't add that in but its definitely best practice.